# One-tailed Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a dataset of paired observations (let's denote X before the treatment and Y after), and I want to test if the distributions are significantly different. Here, I think that a wilcoxon signed-rank test is actually appropriate. Indeed, it gives (in python's scipy) the two-tailed p-value to conclude.

But my question is:**How to say if X is significantly > or < than Y?**

=> My intuition is to use the implemented version of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test to conclude if the two distributions are different, then add another level to the conclusion by computing the median of the variable (X-Y) ? (ex. If >0: X>Y) ?
And it's quite confusing also to use the two-sided p-value to conclude, knowing that the one-sided p-value is half the two-sided one.

Comment: Three things. 1) The wilcoxon signed rank is not the median test. In general they will only correspond if X and Y are the same distribution up to a shift. 2) the p value of the one sided test is equal to half the pvalue of the two sided test (or the complement of the half of the two sided as the case may be). 3) your problem has been solved [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296225/one-sided-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-using-scipy)

Comment: Let's say I achieved the implemented (in python) wilcoxon signed-rank test over two paired vectors X & Y, it will return the two-sided p-value, and I can deduct the one-sided p-value (half the one returned). But how can I ensure that it's right or left. I want just a way to add another level of detail to tell once we know that X and Y are not following the same distribution, if X>Y or X<Y (that's why I evoked the median.

Comment: Oh, that's easy. Just compare `T` (in the code linked to) to `mn`.

Comment: I think now, it's getting more clear thanks (By the way I haven't posted that much, so I'm not yet used to writing formulas here). I just saw that mn = count*(count + 1.) * 0.25 where count is the number of non-zero difference between x and y. And T is the statistic returned by the test

Comment: When T>mn, we can say that the centered quantity computed for the test is positive, and then X>Y?

Comment: yes, that is exactly right. And this will always be consistent with the result of the test, even if X and Y have different distributions.

Comment: I reviewed the full procedure of he test and all the quatities used,

Comment: T= min(r+,r-) where r+ and r- are the number of positive and negative differences while mn=count*(count + 1.) * 0.25. Count is the number of differences computed. Hence, I was wondering, how is comparing r+ to r- different from comparing T to mn ? Thanks!!